# Visual Studio ClickOnce, .NET and Mixed Case

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to publish a .NET 4.0 application to a web server using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) ClickOnce deployment. The actual application is published successfully, but if I start the installation from a machine without .NET 4.0 already installed, setup fails: When I click the download link, I'm getting the following error message:

> An error occurred downloading the following resource:
>       http://server/app/DotNetFX40/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe

A look at the published folder shows that Visual Studio created three folders there, next to setup.exe: `Application Files`, `dotnetfx40` and `windowsinstaller3_1`.

If I change the actual directory name from `dotnetfx40` to `DotNetFX40`, it works.

My "Publishing Folder Location" is a file path (`\\\server\c$\...` etc.), the "Installation Folder URL" is `http://server/app`.

I was surprised that I didn't find anything on this online; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I assume `dotnetfx404` is a typo?

Comment: no, we switched over to copying the binaries from our build machine to the destination instead of deploying from dev machines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: we switched over to copying the binaries from our build machine to the destination instead of deploying from dev machines.

Answer (score 1):

If your web server is a *NIX machine, then **file names are case sensitive**. This means that  `dotnetfx40` and `DotNetFX40` are different files, which would explain why you got an error trying to download one (that didn't exist), and why the other worked.

Comment: Server OS is Windows Server 2008 R2. I changed the directory name *on the server*, that's why it worked afterwards. But obviously this is not a permanent solution, because the next publish will break the directory name again...